# Why is my dax measure still double counting work orders with the same serial number even though I tried to only include distinct workorder serialsials

Tags: powerbi, dax, visualization, dashboard, measure

I want to count the quantity of parts used, but I have to first group the distinct product serial numbers and then group the distinct workorders and each group, sum up the column [actual qty], I see in my table that 2 rows with same workorder numbers are still being summed together

[image: Row showing the 2 duplicate of workorder]

This 2 workorder each have the same product number, and each have an [actual qty] count of 2, (but i am unable to include it in this post because the table is too large), by right, I should get the sum to be =2, however, my code returns me an output of 4 in my table, which is double counting.

Here is my measure code

```
TotalQuantityPerProduct1 = 
SUMX (
    VALUES('PM Checklist vs Last SP Used'[Product]),  -- Get distinct product numbers
    CALCULATE (
        SUMX (
            VALUES('PM Checklist vs Last SP Used'[WO]),  -- Get distinct work orders
            CALCULATE (
                SUM('PM Checklist vs Last SP Used'[Actual Qty]-- Sum up actual quantity
            )
        )
    )
)

)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ultimately, you have `SUM(...)`, and even though it may be looking at just the one instance of `WO` (by **value** not row), it will `SUM` all the values that are of the same `WO`.

Options:

- Remove the Duplicate in PowerQuery
- Swap `SUM` with `MIN` or `MAX` - noting that if there are two of the same `WO` then it will pick the `MIN/MAX` value.

Your measure could look like:

```
TotalQuantityPerProduct2 = 
  SUMX(
    VALUES('PM Checklist vs Last SP Used'[Product]),
    SUMX (
      VALUES('PM Checklist vs Last SP Used'[WO]),
      CALCULATE (
        MAX ('PM Checklist vs Last SP Used'[Actual Qty])
      )
    )
  )
```

Comment: Thank you, you have been of great help to me, do you know how else can I improve my dax coding skills?